# R zip file to specific subfolder in ZIP file

Tags: r, zip, unzip

I am wanting to zip a file into a zip archive in a new subdirectory within the zip archive. Here's my code:

```
dir.create('subdirectory')
write(c(1, 2, 3), file = './subdirectory/test.txt')
zip('test.zip', files = 'subdirectory')
```

The problem is that I do not want to go through the hassle of having to create the subdirectory just to be able to control where the file gets zipped to in the zip archive. What I want to be able to do is something like this:

```
write(c(1, 2, 3), file = 'test.txt')
zip('test.zip/subdirectory', files = 'test.txt')
```

Ideally this would add the file to the archive in the subdirectory folder. Is there any way to do this or am I stuck having to create the folders outside of the zip archive first?

Comment: Should this only work for a new zip archive or do you also want to add files to an existing zip archive?

Comment: An existing zip archive